# How to load a form with camunda embedded REST and Spring?

Tags: java, spring, rest, tomcat, camunda

I took the project at https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/tree/master/deployment/embedded-spring-rest and tried to load a html form which I made and included in the src/main/webapp/forms folder. Now I want simply to load the form when a specific process starts. I tried several things including @RequestMappping annotation but I always got the same link when the process started saying that the resource is not available:

```
http://localhost:8080/camunda-quickstart-embedded-spring-rest/WEB-INF/classes/org/camunda/bpm/example/loanapproval/Starter.java
```

[image]

This is my simple process and I want the form to be loaded when the first user task starts. Where do I configure the resources? I am not using camunda embedded tomcat with the web interface (cockpit, tasklist, ...), just a plain tomcat where I deployed the .WAR file. My .html file is also not written in camunda notation, it's also just a plain html file. 
I put embedded:deployment:forms/request-loan.html in the formKey but it also doesn't work.

Does anybody have an idea? I guess it is just one line of code somewhere, that I have to add so that the right resource is requested and my form opens.
This is how my project structure looks like

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To make forms work, you will have to provide a [ProcessApplication](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/user-guide/process-applications/the-process-application-class/) and an (empty) `META-INF/processes.xml`.

Either use the ServletProcessApplication as a base class or make sure that your process-application sets the context-path property correctly:

```
properties.put(PROP_SERVLET_CONTEXT_PATH, contextPath);
```

Comment: This does not work. The forms never get loaded and I always get a "Form failure: The context path is either empty or not defined."