# Camunda forms not working in any WAR with Spring Framework

Tags: camunda

I can't make ANY project with Spring Framework (NOT Boot) work with the embedded forms. I always get the "Form failure: The context path is either empty or not defined." error.

I tried moving the files from `/resources/static/forms` to `webapp/forms`, and the Camunda Engine still throws this error when trying to load them.

Is there any way to make this work? Spring Boot WAR files deployed to a shared engine present the same problem. Spring Framework the same problem. And I followed the installation procedure provided in the Camunda documentation at:

https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/spring/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an (empty) `META-INF/processes.xml` file in you war? This marks a process archive and is required to bind deployed resources to your process application.

Comment: Saw that you already tried this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44229629/how-to-load-a-form-with-camunda-embedded-rest-and-spring/44237178?noredirect=1#comment118126139_44237178) ... can you share your project setup? How does your form key look like?